# 分類確率とデータの出力方法

Tags: python, 機械学習, tensorflow, keras

機械学習を勉強している大学生です。
python,tensorflow,kerasを用いて2クラス分類を行うプログラムを書いています。

分類確率を`model.predict`で出すことはできるのですが、
その確率値がどのデータに対するものなのかを出力する方法がわかりません。
以下は確率値を出すための部分的なプログラムです。

---

```
result = model.predict(X_test)

import csv
with open('aaa.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    title = ['0', '1']
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)  
    writer.writerow(title)
    writer.writerows(result)
```

---

これを改良したいと思っているのですが、方法がわからずです。
理想としては

ファイル名 0である確率値 1である確率値
1.png 0.9999 0.0001
2.png 0.9999 0.0001
.
.
.
のように出力することです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ご提示のコードの前半の部分がないのですが、
2値分類問題であると仮定して、学習時もlabelの数は2で学習されたと仮定します。

resultには[[データ1のlabel1である確率,データ1のlabel2である確率],[データ2の...]...]
という形で返ってきますので、以下の様にすればよいかと思います。

```
with open('aaa.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    title = ['0', '1']
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)  
    for n, r in zip(X_test[ファイル名のindex], result):
        writer.writerows([n,title[0],r[0],title[1],r[1]])
```

ラベル数が2ではなく1つで学習させたとするならば
(0である確率を出力させるモデルとしたならば)
resultには0の確率のみが返ってきているので1の確率は補数をとれば良いです